# Class attribute not being found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to learn about inheritance in Python and have defined this simple structure :

```
class Request:

    def __init__(self, response):
        self.response = response

    def get_json(self) :
        try:
            return self.response.json()
        except:
            print("An exception occurred - did you set the correct request type ?") 

class GetRequest(Request):

    def __init__(self, url, params):
        self.response = self.get_response(url)
        self.params = params
        print(self.params)

    def get_response(self, url) :
        return requests.get(url , json=self.params)

class PostRequest(Request):

    def __init__(self, url , params):
        self.response = self.get_response(url)
        self.params = params

    def get_response(self, url) :
        return requests.post(url , json=self.params)

r = GetRequest("http://localhost:3000/testpost" , {"key": "value"})
print(r.get_json())

r = GetRequest("http://localhost:3000/testget" , {"key": "value"})
print(r.get_json())

r = PostRequest("http://localhost:3000/testpost" , {"key": "value"})
print(r.get_json())
```

This code returns error :

```
<ipython-input-220-59158abc1bbe> in get_response(self, url)
     23 
     24     def get_response(self, url) :
---> 25         return requests.get(url , json=self.params)
     26 
     27 class PostRequest(Request):

AttributeError: 'GetRequest' object has no attribute 'params'
```

The `params` attribute is defined on the `GetRequest` class so why is it not being found ?

Comment: You are calling `self.response = self.get_response(url)` before `self.params = params`, so `self.params` isn't defined yet (in both `GetRequest.__init__` and `PostRequest.__init__`

Comment: @AndrejKesely great, thanks.

Comment: you shoud call super().__init__()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign `self.params` after calling `self.get_response`, which need `self.params`.
Just move it up:

```py
def __init__(self, url , params):
        self.params = params
        self.response = self.get_response(url)
```